# Heatmaps on R package

Tags: r, heatmap

I'm a student of statistic master degree of Padua. I'm finishing my thesi on models of darts. I've a speed question, Who Can help me?
With this package you estimate the variance of dart's throw for maximize your score!

```
>library(darts)
>e = simpleExpScores(s=25^2)
>drawHeatmap(e)
```

The heatmap is great! But I have not the legend!! 
Do u know put the legend near the heatmap?!

This is my problem, if anyone has 5 min can help me.

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

```
  library(RColorBrewer)
  library(gplots)
  myCol <- c("red", "yellow", "white")
  ## Defining breaks for the color scale
  myBreaks <- c(0, .5, 1, 1.5 )

  hm <- heatmap.2(e, scale="none", Rowv=NA, Colv=NA,
                  col = myCol, ## using your colors
                  breaks = myBreaks, ## using your breaks
                  dendrogram = "none",  ## to suppress warnings
                margins=c(5,5), cexRow=0.5, cexCol=1.0, key=TRUE, keysize=1.5,
                trace="none")
```

Only adjust the breaks as you wish